# Correct guide about spring Oauth 2

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm studying in details the use of spring security (not only oauth), so I'm following this official guide: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle.

This guide have Oauth section and following it I got everything works. But after another research in internet a found a another guide (from pivotal too): https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/.

This second guide use others classes that don't exist in first guide, and other way to configure spring Oauth.

I'm very confused what guide should I follow and what is "more correct".

Answer (score 2):

Both guides are correct.
The first guide you mentioned (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle) uses the newer OAuth 2.0 functionality in the Spring Security project, so it's recommended you use that one.

To give you some background, functionality from the [Spring Security OAuth project](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth) is being migrated to [core Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security).
The first guide you mentioned uses core Spring Security, and the second guide uses the Spring Security OAuth project.
For more information on the features available in the various projects, as well as FAQs, you can check out the [OAuth 2.0 Features Matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix).

Comment: Well, reading the Matrix I noted that Spring Security OAuth project has more things than Spring Security Core, why I should choose Spring Security Core?

Comment: The Spring Security OAuth project is in maintenance mode. If there is a feature that is vital for your product and is not available in the core Spring Security, then you may want to go with Spring Security OAuth. Otherwise, it is recommended to use core Spring Security. Spring Security will have the same features as Spring Security OAuth in future versions, it's currently being worked on.